# No checkbox in wordpress posts list table for CPT

Tags: custom-post-types

I have added a Custom Post Type as follows

```
add_action( 'init', 'codex_book_init' );
function codex_book_init() {
$args = array(
    'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'capabilities' => array(
            'edit_published_posts' => 'do_not_allow' ), //No permission to edit published post, but have permission to delete post
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
);

register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
```

Now when a book post type post is added and published, there is no checkbox in post list table to select multiple post at once. I do not have permission to edit but have permission to delete. So i should have checkbox to select multiple posts and delete.

in Wp_Posts_List_Table method which outputs checkbox

```
public function column_cb( $post ) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ) ): ?>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="cb-select-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php
            printf( __( 'Select %s' ), _draft_or_post_title() );
        ?></label>
        <input id="cb-select-<?php the_ID(); ?>" type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>" />
        <div class="locked-indicator"></div>
    <?php endif;
}
```

So users must have 'edit_post' capability to get that checkbox, but why? how to overcome this?

Comment: If it is true then seems like a feature request to me :)

Comment: I agree with @Sumit that this is a feature request: WP should not test for edit permission here, but for any permission allowing bulk actions. A possible workaround could be to use te [`user_has_cap`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/user_has_cap) filter on the edit page of this cpt to make sure `current_user_can` also returns true if the user has only delete capabilities.